# How to view HTTP commands sent by Cosmos DB SDK V3

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are using OData on top of SQL SDK V3 and we want to view generated queries sent to CosmosDB. I have changed connection mode to Gateway so HTTPS connection is used and I can view dependencies in Application Insights ... but I can only see the URL and it is not clear whether it is GET or POST and no other details.

I have tried Rhino Profiler but it says SDK version is not supported.
I am sure there should be a way to view queries.

Comment: Actually, Rhino profiler works (it was my the error on my side)

Answer (score 1):

I would expect App Insights to also track the verb but the other alternative is to add the logging yourself. You can inject a handler on the pipeline and access the `RequestMessage.Method` property (full solution https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/Handlers/).

```
class LoggingHandler : RequestHandler
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
    public LoggingHandler()
    {
        this.telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
    }

    public override async Task<ResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        RequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        using (Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.IOperationHolder<RequestTelemetry> operation = this.telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("CosmosDBRequest"))
        {
            this.telemetryClient.TrackTrace($"{request.Method.Method} - {request.RequestUri.ToString()}");
            ResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            operation.Telemetry.ResponseCode = ((int)response.StatusCode).ToString();
            operation.Telemetry.Success = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;

            this.telemetryClient.StopOperation(operation);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I Will try the suggestions. Regarding Application Insights I cannot get the verb and query details ... unless it is hidden somewhere - I did look at the log record for this operation. Plus using a Direct connection is a recommended option unless we need a Gateway.